# Do importable libraries exist for common mathematical operations (e.g. min, max and mean) in C or C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, max, shared-libraries

I'm a Python programmer starting to learn C / C++. One issue I'm finding, however, is that the C languages seem to lack a lot of "basic" mathematical operations. For example, even finding the min, max or mean of an array.

Consider finding the maximum value of an array as an example. I appreciate this is an "easy" task and I can write a simple loop that goes through the whole array and compares each element to the current maximum-found value, replacing this maximum with the current element if it exceeds it. However, it's annoying in each project I'm working on to have to define such commonly used functions.

Therefore, I wonder if there are widely used / accepted C & C++ libraries for such mathematical operations (i.e. similar to numpy for Python), which would save time and limit the chance of me introducing bugs by re-writing commonly used algorithms?

More generally, would this be considered bad practice in C/C++ programs - do such programmers simply expect to see everything coded up from first principles?

Thanks

Comment: For C, such libraries exist, but they are not standard — usually you have to find the library you want and install it on your system yourself.

Comment: *do such programmers simply expect to see everything coded up from first principles?* No, that is a terrrible idea in any language.  Unless you need something one-off/custom, use the built in stuff as it is normally as good or better then you can do yourself.

Comment: There's a lot in the C++ [algorithm library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for instance [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). You need to decide whether you want to learn C or C++; they are very different languages.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include <algorithm>`

This seems to be what you are looking for.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/

This website is also a good reference just in general for c++ libraries.

Comment: I recommend changing or adding a link to cppreference; it's more up to date. Also worth noting that `<algorithm>` doesn't have a simple mean function like OP wanted.

Comment: Not only `<algorithm>`, but `<numeric>`, too.

Comment: Thanks (to Cameron & all) for the insightful comments and discussion that followed. These libraries sound useful - will investigate them more now.